# Retrieving pid of tasklet

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, interrupt

How can I get the pid of the task executing the tasklet function. current->pid wont work since tasklets run in interrupt context. current will most likely refer to the task that was interrupted.

Comment: As far as I know, `current` **always** returns task which is currently run. The only exception is absent of the task, corresponded to currently executed thing: in that case `current` returns NULL. In other words, if `current` returns non-NULL then this is currently executed task. If `current` returns NULL then currently executed thing is not a task.

Answer (score 0):

Pass it in from the task you need the pid to.

```
static DECLARE_TASKLET(ttasklet, &ttasklet_work, (unsigned long)&tshared_data);
```

In your code somewhere in process context or where you can get the pid then add the pid to the struct `tshared_data.`